# How do I make the buildings not have a medieval look?

Tags: cities-skylines

Is it just me or is there a new update to Cities: Skylines that makes all your buildings look medieval? I don't really like the look of them and I don't know how to change it. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: I do not own Skylines, so I don't know if there has been such patch. But assuming that this is not a widely known thing (patch or some other problem), maybe you could give us a screenshot to show what exactly seems to be the problem. The question now seems rather vague.

Comment: I would assume he's asking about the new European themed buildings that came in the latest major patch.

Comment: @JMR Perhaps, but we don't know that for sure.  It's usually not a good idea to modify a question that drastically, especially when we have no additional information from the asker.  To that end, I have rolled it back.

Comment: @JMR - I wouldn't call the European buildings as "Medieval" lol

Comment: @Tony - Sure, that's not the word I would use either, but I think it's pretty clear that's what he's talking about. New patch, adds a new set of buildings, they look different. He probably started a new city on one of the European maps without knowing about the patch and was surprised at the new buildings.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about buildings that look like this:

[image]

Then you're seeing the European style buildings introduced in version 1.1.0 of the game, released 19th May 2015. You can see the patch notes [here](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/content-update-1-1-0-is-live-on-retail.856707/)

These buildings are what the developers call a map theme (or biome, they used both in the link above), meaning that whether you see the original or European style depends on the map you are playing on and cannot be changed for that map.

You can see this information somewhere on the map selection screen, before you start your city (I'm not in a position to start the game for a screenshot and didn't quickly find an example). I do not think there is a way to change the theme of a map either before starting or once your city is going.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to DMA57361's answer, if you're willing to go the mod route, there is a mod that makes the building theme a function of a city/district policy instead of the map biome:

[Building Themes mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=466158459)

The mod maker has even made the mod open to additional "themes" that can be created by users. Currently, there are three user made themes along with the two included in the vanilla game:

[UK Terraced Housing](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=470539837)

[Neo-eclectic homes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=471015559)

[American trailer homes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=471183698)

Comment: Oh _very_ nice, I'm certainly giving that UK housing style a spin when I get home this evening.